# Simplifying this Boolean term

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Can someone help me with simplifying this Boolean term

$$(y + z')(x' + w) + (x + y')(w' + z)$$

$$x'= \mathrm{not} \quad x$$

I know it can be simplified into $1$, but I don't know how.

Can you please show me step by step and the laws which you have applied in simplifying?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use the law of distributivity first on both sides.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried putting up a truth table? I would guess that's the most straight forward way to prove things like these - at least when other attemts fails. Or if you use Karnaugh diagrams you get another visual of whats going on.

Comment: Another approach is to expand the conjunctions using the distributive law. Then you use complement law together with that to make even more terms until you have terms for all 16 combos which you then combine with the distributive law together with the complement law until you're left with only $1$. It's a bit of work, but it should eventually bring you to to the conclusion.

Comment: @Wuestenfux How do you apply the law of distributivity? It states that A + (B.C) = (A + B).(A + C). There is no common A in the expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the  second term as it is.

First,note that $(y+z')(x'+w) = (y'z)'(xw')' = (y'z+xw')'$. by De Morgan.

Also, by the law that $(a+b)(a+c) = a+bc$ , we get $((y'z + xw'))' = ((y'z+x)(y'z+w'))' = ((y'+x)(z+x)(y'+w')(z+w'))'$,

which then becomes again using De Morgan, $((y'+x)(w'+z))' + ((z+x)(w'+y'))'$.

Hence, we get in total:
$$
(x+y')(w'+z) + ((y'+x)(w'+z))' + ((z+x)(w'+y'))'
$$

By the rule that $a+a' = 1$ and $1+b=1$, it's easy to see that the above expression is $1$.

Main rules used : De Morgan, and $(a+b)(a+c) = a+bc$

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you share with me your train of thought? Because all the laws you have applied I am familiar with them. However, I am so lost when applying them to simplify. Like I don't  know where to start as there are so many possibilities

Comment: @Anlinyang I've only typed the answer. My train of thought took about 15+ minutes to reach the right destination. Honestly, there's no "formula" to do these questions, it just comes from practice. In this case, I first expanded, then tried to work it out, and failed, before hitting this method. I am also often lost when I see these kind of problems, it just so happens I got it right here. So I would just ask you to practice more of these problems, because that's what I did. You are welcome. Also, I like your question, so +1.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your help! I learnt!